# Crontab not executing .sh

Tags: cron

I have made a project on my Raspberry PI and it is working fine except for the `crontab` routine. I have read a lot about the subject but can not find the fault.
When I run this script

```
/home/icf/catFeeder/checkDispenseFood.sh
```

in the terminal it runs fine.

This is the  `checkDispenseFood.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /
cd home/icf/catFeeder
sudo python checkDispenseFood.py
cd /
```

The owner of `checkDispenseFood` is root and the permissions are everybody/alone owner/everybody.

When I check my cronlog I see this :

```
Jul 25 10:00:01 raspberrypi CRON[1850]: (root) CMD /home/icf/catFeeder/checkDispenseFood.sh >> /home/icf/logs/cronlog)
Jul 25 10:00:01 raspberrypi CRON[1849]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

And exact on the hour as set.

This is the cron I find with `sudo crontab -e`:

```
0 * * * * /home/icf/catFeeder/checkDispenseFood.sh >> /home/icf/logs/cronlog
```

But nothing happens.
What am I missing ?

Comment: If you run the script as root, why is the script using `sudo`?  Does the script produce output? Is the issue that you don't see the output? By default, if a cron job produces errors or other output, it is mailed to the owner of the job, but since you don't even have local delivery of mails set up, this fails. Consider redirecting the _errors_ of the script to the log file too.  You do this with `>>logfile 2>&1`.

Comment: Thank you  The script is supposed to produce output ( stepper motor running by the py file) as it does when running it manually in the terminal.  Should i remove the sudo in the script ?  I will add the error command in the crontab.  Grts Patrick  This is all very new to me. :-)

Comment: Yes, remove `sudo` from the script, as the script is already running as `root`. The `cd` commands seem unecessary too, you could just do `python /home/icf/catFeeder/checkDispenseFood.py`. Also, Why do you have this `sh` wrapper script? You can run the `.py` script directly from the crontab.

Comment: This is a project from somebody else on instructables. As a newby I do not know why he did it like that. I will change it and see if it works.   Thx

Comment: You would improve your chances of getting a helpful answer if you could at least reference the location of this project. It seems that [the` instructables` website specializes in automated cat feeders](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=instructables+cat+feeder&atb=v278-1&ia=web).

Answer (score 0):

I've had to make some assumptions in my answer, so this is a best guess:

I do not see the need for the `.sh` script at all. You may run the Python script from the `crontab` as shown below.

I cannot comment on the ***need*** for elevated privileges (`sudo`), but since you are using `root's crontab`, any script will be executed with elevated privileges. You *should not* use `sudo` in any program/script that is run from `root's crontab`.

If you do actually need elevated privileges for this cat feeder, use this line in the `root crontab`:

```
0 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/icf/catFeeder/checkDispenseFood.py >> /home/icf/catFeeder/cronlog.txt 2>&1
```

This `crontab` entry will run the designated .py script using your system's **default version** of Python. You can check your system default from the command line as follows:

```
python --version
```

Make sure your .py script is compatible with the system default. If not, change the default, or change your script.

WRT the messages you shared from your cronlog:

1. The last character in the first message is a "close parenthesis" `)`, and it appears to be *unmatched*, possibly suggesting a user input error??
2. The second message indicates that you do not have a Mail Transfer Agent (MTA) installed on your Raspberry Pi. If you are using RPiOS (née Raspbian) there is no MTA in the default distribution, **HOWEVER** `cron` (by default) only contacts the MTA when there is no valid redirect for output from your job. Therefore, it would seem that you had not properly configured your redirect. I think the `crontab` line supplied above will capture the output and errors from your program.

Hope this helps & let us know if not.